# Why is IntelliJ giving me the name of the package and the name of another package in brackets?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

(Side-note: the GameLogic module is not imported anywhere and can be ignored.)

As you can see in the picture under this, the java file of the 'ConsoleApp' labels '[DesktopApp]' next to it, but the DesktopApp module does not. The pom.xml of both the ConsoleApp and the DesktopApp module do not reference eachother, so how come IntelliJ labels the source folder this way?

[image]

The `ConsoleApp/pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>TicTacToe</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>ConsoleApp</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

The `DesktopApp/pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>TicTacToe</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>DesktopApp</artifactId>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

The `pom.xml` (Parent `pom.xml`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TicTacToe</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>GameLogic</module>
        <module>DesktopApp</module>
        <module>ConsoleApp</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Feel free to ask for more information!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be caused by the fact that you marked your Java folder as a module folder instead of a source folder. Go to the Project Structure Settings and remove the module named after the Java folder. Then go to the module console app and mark the Java folder as sources.

Comment: Ok I don't know what it exactly was, but deleting the DesktopApp module and remaking it fixed it, so thanks for telling me to the ProjectStructure menu (didn't know it existed)

Comment: The same just happened to me for several older Python projects. I haven't looked into it, but apparently there were deeper changes in the recent versions of JetBrains IDEs about how sources roots are marked and displayed in the Project View.